# What is difference between Mono and MonoSink in Java?

Tags: java, project-reactor

both `Mono` and `MonoSink` comes under **reactor.core.publisher**

I am new to reactive programming and I recently found

`private final MonoSink<MyModel1> sink;`
`private final Mono<MyModel2> mono;`

I am confused about their difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#mono) is *an Asynchronous 0-1 Result* (i.e. either a result or no result, but it cannot represent multiple results - for that you would need a [`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#flux)).

[`MonoSink`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) is used to bridge between multithreaded code and reactive code (a `Mono`).

A similar pattern exists for `Flux` and `FluxSink`.